# How to extract numbers (including scientific notation) in lines

Tags: grep

I have a txt file with the following data:

```
Time = `number`6e-05
Time = `number`6.16667e-05 
Time = `number`6.25581e-05 
Time = `number`6.35182e-05 
Time = `number`6.45605e-05 
Time = `number`6.57037e-05 
Time = `number`6.6974e-05
...
```

The file contains around 13,000 lines

Is there a grep command to extract just the numbers and write it in an another file?.

This file is being generated using a grep command from another huge file.

Comment: Give us the  `grep` command and original data file.  No need to first `grep` then use an extra command to get data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the original file called `data.txt` then:

```
$ awk -F "\`" '{print $3}' data.txt > result.txt
$ cat result.txt
6e-05
6.16667e-05 
6.25581e-05 
6.35182e-05 
6.45605e-05 
6.57037e-05 
6.6974e-05
```

If you want to get the label value which marked as `number` in your question, just change the number `3` to `2` is ok. Like this:

```
awk -F "\`" '{print $2}' data.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is `nums.txt` then:

```
$ egrep -o "[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?." nums.txt > other.file
$ cat other.file
6e-05
6.16667e-05
6.25581e-05
6.35182e-05
6.45605e-05
6.57037e-05
6.6974e-05
```

ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
awk -F\` '$0=$NF' old >new
6e-05
6.16667e-05
6.25581e-05
6.35182e-05
6.45605e-05
6.57037e-05
6.6974e-05
```